# How can I have my search check for objects on other pages but display on the current page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I have a javascript search bar on my site to search images based on a div classed text which acts as their name. 
However I plan on having several hundred images which would not be suitable for one page, which is why I added pages to my site, which brings me to my question. 
How would I allow for a user regardless of what page they are on to use the search bar to search images from other pages and have that data displayed on their current page 
I would like to try and do this without setting up a back end database which is where I feel this is headed, if anyone has any solutions please shoot them my way.
Below will be the html and css of my index as the second page is identical to the first other than the images. All my images are locally hosted, so if you want a running example on codepen, just comment and I will set that up.

```js
<script>


$("#myinput").keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value);
    if (val === "")
        $('img').show();
    else {
        $('img').hide();
        val = val.split(" ").join("\\ ");
        console.log(val)
        $("img[alt*=" + val + " i]").show();
    }
});

$(".img").wrap('<div class="alt-wrap"/>');

$(".img").each(function() {
    $(this).after('<p class="alt">' + $(this).attr('alt') + '</p>');
  })
   
</script>
```

```css
/* Website Title */
h1 {
 color: red;
} 
/* Website desciption */
h2 {
 color:red;
}
/* Text */
p {
 font-family: Arial;
}
/* Website body */
body {
 background-color: grey;
}
/*Navigation Bar */
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: black;
}

li {
 float: left;
 border-right: 1px solid white;
 padding: 10px;
}

li a {
 display: block;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: upercase;
 font-size: 30px;
}

li:last-child {
 border-right: none;
}

ul li:hover:not(.active) {
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
}

.active {
 background-color: red;
}

/* Search Bar */
input[type=text] {
    width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
 font-size: 30px;
}

/* Cool code but not needed atm
input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 100%;
 float: left;
}
*/

/* Keeps images inline */ 
.alt-wrap { 
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      margin: 20px;
      color: whitesmoke;
      border: 1px solid mediumorchid;
}
/*Puts overlay on images */
.alt-wrap p.alt {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0; /* hide initially */
      left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 15px;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 22px;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      transition: all 300ms ease;
      transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.alt-wrap:hover > p.alt { 
      opacity: 1; 
      transition-delay: 0s;
}
    
.imgContainer{
    float:left;
}

img {
 width: 200px !important; 
}

body {
 background: white !important; 
}

.imgContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.imgContainer:hover .overlay {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.dl {
margin-top: 400px; 
}

/* For links for the pages */
.pagination a {
 color: black;
 padding: 8px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: background-color .3s;
}


/* Styling current page buttons */
.pagination a.active {
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 color: white;
}

/* Styling on mouse-over background color for page buttons */
.pagination a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}


/*Forcing footer to the bottom*/
html, body, #wrap { height: 100%; }
body > #wrap { height: auto; min-height: 100%;}
#main { padding-bottom: 10px; } /* Must equal the height of the footer */

#footer {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: -10px; /*Must equal negative value of the footer height */
 height: 10px;
 clear: both;
 padding-top: 20px;
}

.clearfix:after {
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
}

.clearfix {
 display: inline-block;
}
/* End of forcing footer to the bottom*/
```

```html
<html>
 <title>Cryptos Explained</title>
 
 <head>
  <!-- Links to my CSS document -->
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  
  <!-- My main heading -->
  <h1 align=center>Cryptos Explained</h1>
  
  <!-- My Sub-heading -->
  <h2 align=center>Explainations, Prices, WhitePapers and more</h2>
  
  <!-- Allows me to have jquery code at the bottom of the page -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <!-- Kind of makes it mobile friendly -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  
   <header>
    <!-- Navigation bar -->
    <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Vocabulary</a></li>
     <input type="text" id="myinput" name="search" placeholder="Search..." style="border-radius: 4px;">
    </ul>
   </header><br>
   
 <body>
  <!--Lots of Div classes so I can seperate the main and the footer -->
  <div id="wrap">
   <div id="main" class="clearfix">
    <!-- All my images -->
    <div class="image123">
    
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="cryptos/generic.html"><img src="img/btc.png" alt="Bitcoin"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Bitcoin</div></div></a>
     </div>
      
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/ethereum.png" alt="Ethereum"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Ethereum</div></div></a>
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/ripple.png" alt="Ripple"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Ripple</div></div></a>
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/Bitcoin_Cash.png" alt="Bitcoin Cash"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Bitcoin Cash</div></div></a>
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/ada.png" alt="Cardano"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Cardano</div></div></a>
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/NEM.png" alt="NEM"> <div class="overlay"><div class="text">NEM</div></div></a>
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/Litecoin.png" alt="LiteCoin"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">LiteCoin</div></div></a>
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/stellar.png" alt="Stellar Lumens"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Stellar Lumens</div></div></a>   
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/iota.png" alt="IOTA"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">IOTA</div></div></a>   
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/dash.png" alt="Dash"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Dash</div></div></a>   
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/neo.png" alt="NEO"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">NEO</div></div></a>   
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/tron.png" alt="Tron"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Tron</div></div></a>   
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/monero.png" alt="Monero"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Monero</div></div></a>   
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/eos.png" alt="EOS"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">EOS</div></div></a>   
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/icon.png" alt="ICON"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">ICON</div></div></a>   
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/bitcoingold.png" alt="Bitcoin Gold"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Bitcoin Gold</div></div></a>   
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/qtum.svg" alt="QTUM"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">QTUM</div></div></a>   
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/ethereum_classic.png" alt="Ethereum Classic"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Ethereum Classic</div></div></a>   
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/raiblocks.png" alt="RaiBlocks"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">RaiBlocks</div></div></a>   
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/lisk.png" alt="Lisk"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Lisk</div></div></a>   
     </div>
     
     <div class="imgContainer">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/verge.png" alt="Verge"><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Verge</div></div></a>   
     </div>
     
   </div>
    <!-- Pages -->
    <div id="footer">
     <div class="pagination" align="center">
      <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
      <a class="active" href="#">1</a>
      <a href="page2.html">2</a>
      <a href="#">3</a>
      <a href="#">4</a>
      <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
 
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: well yeah a database would be the easier solution.. but you could always just create a function that checks all the files in your img folder or in an image folder hoster somewhere. 

Or you could also save each image url to a specific text file which you will refer to when the user searches...

Comment: Use a `<script>` tag, if it's raw JavaScript data, or use AJAX to `JSON.parse(xhrJSONresponse)`.

Comment: Could you use jQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to query the pages? i.e. `$( ".image123" ).load( 'images/page1.html .imgContainer .text:contains("' + searchedText + '")' );`

Comment: I will look into the Jquery Load method by @Quantastical but initial tests have proven unsuccessful